# Where is List<T>.IsReadOnly?

Tags: .net, list, interface

In the .Net Framework, `List<T>` implements the `ICollection<T>` interface. However when looking at the List class in Visual Studio, I see no `IsReadOnly` property, which is supposedly in the `ICollection<T>` interface.

How is it possible for a class to implement an interface... but not really implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses [*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). For example:

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    void Bar();
}

public Foo : IFoo
{
    // Note the lack of public here
    void IFoo.Bar() {}
}
```

Comment: I hate it when an object implements `IDisposable` in this way. You type `.D`, and `Dispose` doesn't appear, and you think, okay, and years later you suddenly find out you should have been `using` that object because it must be disposed in fact.

Answer (score 2):

`IsReadOnly` is listed under the Explicit Interface Implementations section of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's made using an explicit interface implementation. You can only see the implementation when you use the list as that specific interface:

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();

bool b1 = x.IsReadOnly; // not accessible

ICollection<T> y = x;

bool b2 = y.IsReadOnly; // accessible
```